# Combining multiple grails applications

Tags: grails, groovy, view, controllers

I have been building multiple grails applications, which are basically just the different tabs (4) of my web dashboard. I had initially thought I could simply make a sidebar and use different views, their corresponding controllers and also their corresponding domain classes simultaneously in my final single grails application.

But, after reading the documentation I don't think this is feasible. Or am I wrong here?

So, I need to combine all of these and make one final grails application with a sidebar having 4 options there, wherein on clicking on each of the options - a different view is rendered.
But these different views are connected to different controllers and different domain classes.

Can these all be combined into one grails application? If yes, how do I go about accomplishing it?

I cannot find any documentation regarding these. 
One useful link : http://javadeveloper.asia/grails-ajax-tutorial-remotelink-tag/

Any suggestions/approaches will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "mutiple grails applications" and then "one final grails application". If you mean, you have 4 wars, then just do a link like <a href="http://app1.mydomain.com">My First App</a>. Of course you could do this within like tabs (jqury-ui tabs with a ajax content sould be fine). Or do you mean you have four plugins that are all used by one "final app"? if so, then you could just link to a controller action of of of these plugins with <g:link controller="controllerFromApp1">My App 1</g:link>

Comment: "multiple grails apps" - I have created different apps for different tabs of my web dashboard. I don't have a clear idea on how to combine all of these tabs (apps) into one and having a sidebar/topbar which goes into each of the view. None of the apps are in the deployment stage yet.

Comment: why do you want to seperate the different views in different apps at all? if there is no reason --> put it into one app. If there is one, my first idea would be to create different grails plugins for these artefacts. Then create an dashboard app, that uses these plugins. After this, the linking via controller works fine...

Comment: There was no reason, I just didn't know how to do it in one app.
How do we have different views in one application if they connect to different controllers and different domain classes? Is it possible to connect various views to corresponding controllers and corresponding domain classes? If yes, can you pls guide me how to?

Comment: ok, the default way of doing it is just to create different domain types under the grails-app/domain folder. And then create different controllers for these domain types. A sample application is the [grails petclinic](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic), where you find a working example...